# ROS Class Issue: Subscriber not modifying object correctly C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor, callback, ros

Been beating my head against the wall for a while now, and am almost embarrassed to ask the community since it will most likely result in me getting schooled for a pointer or scoping .

I am using ROS to manipulate a robot that has two arms; each arm has a gripper.  I have an arm class and a gripper class; the gripper is a member of the arm class.  Relevant code posted below.

To sum up my code: the gripper class has members such as `id` which need to be initialized by the `callback` function.  If these members are accessed before the callback is called, they will get bad data.  Therefore, the class has an `initialized_` variable and associated `initialized()` function, which simply checks to see if the callback has been called yet (initialized is set to false when constructed, then set to true in the callback).  The design pattern for the arm class is similar; its `initialize()` function checks to see if the gripper is initialized.  In the main function, in my ros loop, I check to make sure the arms are both initialized; if not, ros spins (aka calls the callbacks) until the callbacks initialize the grippers, allowing the program to continue.

To sum up my problem: the gripper's callback function is definitely being called, since "gripper initialized" is being printed.  However, the properties it sets are not being retained, since "success!" is not being printed. Furthermore, an id of -1 is printed, a value set by the constructor rather than by the callback (an id of -1 is impossible).

Smells like a scoping or pointer issue, but I can't seem to find the problem.  Since callback functions modify the "this" object, it is modifying the gripper itself, and that modification should remain after the function exits.

If anyone can offer help, it would be very greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
class Gripper
{
    private: 
        int id;
        bool initialized_;
        ros::Subscriber subscriber;
        void callback(const baxter_core_msgs::EndEffectorState::ConstPtr& msg);
        void init();

    public:
        Gripper();
        Gripper(ros::NodeHandle handle); 
        bool initialized() { return this->initialized_; }
        int get_id() { return this->id; }
};

// DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
Gripper::Gripper()
{
    this->init();
    ...
}

// CONSTRUCTOR
Gripper::Gripper(ros::NodeHandle handle)
{
    this->init();
    this->subscriber = handle.subscribe(sub_topic, 10, &Gripper::callback, this);
    ...
}

// CALLBACK FUNCTION
// initializes gripper fields
void Gripper::callback(const baxter_core_msgs::EndEffectorState::ConstPtr& msg) 
{
    this->initialized_ = true;
    this->id = msg->id;
    ...
    if (this->initialized_) ROS_INFO("gripper initialized");
}

// INIT FUNCTION
// common code in constructors
// sets all bools to false, ints to -1
void Gripper::init() 
{
    this->initialized_ = false;
    this->id = -1;
    ...
}

class Arm
{
    public:
        Gripper gripper;
        Arm();
        Arm(ros::NodeHandle handle); 
        bool initialized() 
        { 
            if (this->gripper.initialized()) ROS_INFO("success!");
            ROS_INFO("gripper id: %d");    
            return this->gripper.initialized(); 
        };

};

// DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
Arm::Arm() 
{
    this->gripper = gripper();
    ...
}

// CONSTRUCTOR
Arm::Arm(ros::NodeHandle handle)
{
    this->gripper = gripper(handle); 
    ...
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // initialize the node and create a node handle
    ros::init(argc, argv, "master_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

    // make some variables for later
    Arm left_arm(nh, LEFT);
    Arm right_arm(nh, RIGHT);

    // main program content
    while (ros::ok()) 
    {
        // if everything is initialized, start doing the stuff
        if (left_arm.initialized() && right_arm.initialized()) 
        {
                ...
        }

        // spin & sleep
        ROS_INFO("spin");
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to learn what [member initialization lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list) are.  This line `this->gripper = gripper();` -- What are you expecting that line to do (and this `this->gripper = gripper(handle);`)?

Comment: `ros::NodeHandle handle` is pass by value. I don't know `ros`, but looking at the documentation for `ros::NodeHandle`, the sucker looks awfully heavy weight for something being copied all over the place. I'm not sure the subscription process will work as you expect once the copy of the `ros::NodeHandle` you subscribed to goes out of scope.

Comment: Huh. Son of a gun. It sounds like it's reference counted. Didn't expect that. I take back most of my previous comment. It still creeps me out, though.

Comment: All member variables must be fully constructed when you enter the body of the constructor. `this->gripper = gripper();` means you constructed twice. Member initializer list gets around this, but in the case of default construction you don't need to do this at all. `this->gripper` is default constructed for you. `this->gripper = gripper(handle);` on the other hand required default construction, construction with `handle` and then assignment. Lot of extra work.

Comment: A big thank you to PaulMcKenzie and user4581301 for their tips on initializer lists: that was exactly my problem.